# How to use bears admitting?

Tags: meaning, word-meaning

I was reading an article and come across the following phrase "bears admitting" what does it mean. i have tried to googled it but no luck of finding an answer. I think it must be a new word or not a common word.

The context it is used is

> Yet, it bears admitting that this
>   model represents an ideal of fairness that may seldom be
>   achieved, that strong disagreements may exist on how to
>   value worker investments or contributions, and that inconsistencies and hypocrisy can often be found in the way the
>   model is applied to various situations.

Comment: "It bears admitting" means "it should be considered." The *verb* [**bear**](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/bear) as in "I can bear responsibility" etc.

Answer (score 1):

I think that [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bear) offers the correct meaning of **bear** in this context:

> b: to call for as suitable or essential
>   *it bears watching*

There is also an entry for the expression "It [bears repeating](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bear%20repeating) that..." which means "to be important enough to state more than once".

So "It bears admitting..." means that it's important enough, or maybe essential, to state 
something- despite the fact that that is counter to the main argument: in this case, that the model rarely delivers the ideal of fairness that it should do.

Comment: Your analysis is correct, but I think M-W overstates the definition.  If something "bears repeating" it is not essential to repeat it, but rather it is reasonable to repeat it.  "Suitable" is a much more appropriate word in this definition than is "essential."